# Nodejs Website doesn't display second mysql table value

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I have a express website that display values in the mysql. It displays the news but it doesn't display events. I know for sure that the events table has 2 values in it.

here is my index.js file in the routes:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

//connection variables
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host: 'localhost',
port: '3306',
user: 'root',
password: 'mypassword*',
database: 'icomnodejs'

});

 connection.connect();

 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

 connection.query('SELECT * FROM news', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('index', {
        'news' : rows
        });
   });
});

 router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM events', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render('index', {
        'events': rows
          });
      });
  });

 module.exports = router;
```

And here is my view file called index.handlebars

```
 <div class="row">
    {{#if news}}
        {{#each news}}

            <div class="col-md-4 img-portfolio">
                <a href="portfolio-item.html">
                    <img class="img-responsive img-hover" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="portfolio-item.html">{{title}}</a>
                </h3>
                <p>{{text}}</p>
            </div>
            {{/each}}
         </div>

{{else}}
<p>No News</p>
{{/if}}

    <hr>

    <!-- Marketing Icons Section -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h1 class="page-header">
                Upcoming Events Lopping As well
            </h1>
        </div>

        {{#if events}}
            {{#each events}}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4><i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i> {{title}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <p>{{text}}</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">Learn More</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        {{/each}}
        {{else}}
        <p>No events</p>
        {{/if}}

    </div>
```

Based on the view file, I see news from the database but I don't see events. I just don't see where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you misunderstood the concept of express middlewares and routes. You are registering against the same path different router handlers. Something like that will do what you need:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mysql = require('mysql');

//connection variables
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  port: '3306',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'mypassword*',
  database: 'icomnodejs'

});

connection.connect();

function getNews(req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM news', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    };

    req._news = rows;
    return next();
  });
}

function getEvents(req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM events', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    };

    req._events = rows;
    return next();
  });
}

router.get('/', getNews, getEvents, function (req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', {
    'news': req._news,
    'events': req._events
  });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: You're right. I think I should study on express middlewares and routes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I have aother question. What if I wanted to display two different value in the same table. Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124989/display-count-value-in-the-mysql-database-table-using-handlebars-in-nodejs-proje)