# Display count value in the mysql database table using handlebars in Nodejs project

Tags: mysql, node.js, http, get, handlebars.js

I have a webpage that displays number of applications in certain grades. For example, number of applications in grade 6, grade 7 and grade 8. The functions that I use for grade 6 and grade 7 are as below:

```
function getGrade6Applicants(req, res, next) {
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS grade_6 FROM applications WHERE grade="Grade 6" ', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    };
    req._applications = rows;
    return next();
});}

function getGrade7Applicants(req, res, next) {
connection.query('SELECT COUNT(*) AS grade_7 FROM applications WHERE grade="Grade 7" ', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        return next(err);
    };
    req._applications = rows;
    return next();
});}
```

Then I use this function to my GET request as below. If it's just for grade_6, it works fine. The name of the mysql table is "applications".

```
/* GET dashboard page */
router.get('/dashboard', getGrade6Applicants, function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('admission/dashboard', {
       'applications': req._applications
   });
})
```

This gives me the number of applications in grade6 in my applications table in mysql database.

I use this in my dashboard.handlebars page as {{grade_6}} using appropriate {{#if}} and {{#each}} built in helpers.

The problem is whenever I wanted to add second function to display number of applications in grade 7, what I have is only grade 7 applications. Grade 6 is not shown. Here is the GET request that I use for multiple values:

```
/* GET dashboard page */
router.get('/dashboard', getGrade6Applicants, getGrade7Applicants, function (req, res, next) {
   res.render('admission/dashboard', {
       'applications': req._applications
   });
})
```

Comment: Each of your getGradeXApplications overwrite the same variable to store their results - req._applications.

Comment: So how not to override and get different results so I can use it on the webpage?

Comment: Several ways: use different variable name, push into an array, etc

Comment: I think I am going to need you to explain more on using different variable.

Comment: Sure.  You could use `req._applications6 = rows` for the grade6 data and `req._applications7 = rows` for the grade7 data, etc.  Then in your code send `{ 'applications6': req._applications6, 'applications7': req._applications7 }` to the dashboard renderer.

Comment: I tried that already and it didn't work. I see nothing on the page.

Comment: Did you change your template to match your new variables?

Comment: I used **{{grade_6}}**  and **{{grade_7** in the dashboard renderer. Isn't something that I can use?

Comment: Lets see your `router.get('/dashboard' ...` code now that you've changed it.

Comment: `router.get('/dashboard', getGrade7Applicants, getGrade8Applicants, function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('admission/dashboard', {
        'applications7': req._applications7,
        'applications8': req._applications8

       
    });
})`

Comment: Shouldn't you instead use `applications6`, `applications7` and `applications8` in your template?  I'm not sure you understand how variables are mapped to the template.

Comment: I tried all possible ways and nothing is working. Can you post your code as a response to this post please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution that works:

my router js file:

```
router.get('/dashboard', getGrade7Applicants, getGrade8Applicants, function (req, res, next) {
res.render('admission/dashboard', {
    applications: {
            'grade7': req._applications7[0],
            'grade8': req._applications8[0],
    }

});
});
```

And here is the html template:

```
 {{#if applications}}
     {{#if applications.grade7}}
         {{applications.grade7.grade7}}
      {{/if}}
     .......
   {{#if applications.grade8}}
         {{applications.grade8.grade8}}
      {{/if}}
{{/if}}
```